# Can I sent the localized text through the `write` command?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

If I send the localized text through the `write` command, then the recipient gets not the same that I sent:

```
user@host ~ $ write test pts/0
привет
```

The recipient gets it:

```
Message from user@host on pts/1 at 17:56 ...
M-PM-?M-QM-^@M-PM-8M-PM-2M-PM-5M-QM-^B
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely this is the answer (I don't know how to mark the question as duplicate):
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39759/using-utf-8-chars-with-write-message-program

Example of writing directly to terminal:

[root@galene alex]# echo "message from root at $(date) ¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás? Привет! Как дела?" >/dev/pts/3

[katya@galene ~]$ message from root at Вс фев  2 21:54:13 NOVT 2014 ¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás? Привет! Как дела?

But actually I'd suggest you to choose some other notification style. Do your users have a [fully-functional] X session? If they do you might use a system tray notifications sent via D-Bus.

Comment: This is the same problem, but the link not contain the solution. Are exist the other similar utility which correctly works with unicode characters?

Comment: Well, you may send an e-mail :-) bsdmail is 8-bit clean :) Or if you have superuser permissions you may write directly to a given console:

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. I learn the Linux through the book now.